# Qt Application show black window on Windows 10 after restart from hibernate

Tags: windows, qt

I develop Qt application and run this application on Windows. Then I find one strange problem when I run it. After restart the machine from hibernate state, the application's widget show black screen, but I can operate the controls on this widget.

I don't know what happened! Is someone has also encounter this problem?

Comment: I found this problem  maybe caused by QWebEngine. I use QWebEngine show some html page in app, and when I wake up the windows, the widget show black screen. when I close the QtWebEngineProcess.exe, the widget show, the QWebEngineView disappear meanwhile.